# Xslt changes nodes letter to lowercase

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I want to create KML code from Xml by using xslt
the problem is that xslt changes all the letters of the nodes to lowercase
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="tasks/task">
        <kml >
            <Placemark>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="title"/></name>
                <description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="abilities"/>
                </description>
                <Point><coordinates><xsl:value-of select="geotag"/></coordinates></Point>
            </Placemark>
        </kml>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is when i use the next javascript code to get the output of the xslt, i get the nodes Placemark and Point in lower case!

```
var xsltTasksAsKml = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(xsltTasksAsKml);
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

how can i handle that problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never heard of a problem like this. What does your input XML look like?

Comment: is it possible that the lower case letters is because of i am reading the string from div.innerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving this document as text/html rather than application/xhtml+xml then innerHTML will use the HTML parser which is (mostly) case insensitive so will not necessarily preserve the element names. You can serve the document as XHTML (if it is well formed) or explicitly call the xml parser from javascript to parse the XSLT script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. should i set the content "application/xhtml+xml" when creating the div? because i changed it on the document but didn't work:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml">

Comment: best to set it on the server actually but changing this changes the interpretation of the whole document, just accessing the xml parser directly is a less intrusive change

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

`xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);`

into

`xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);`

This eliminates the dependency on the "owning" document. For me, this solved a very similar issue.

Comment: Thanks, for me this is the better answer.